# Why does my 3d model become invisible as I move the camera away?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to load a 3d model from Mixamo:

//        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Ch45_nonPBR.dae")!

```
    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    scene.fogStartDistance = 10000
    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 40, z: 100)

    // create and add a light to the scene
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = .omni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 50, z: 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
    lightNode.light?.intensity = 10000;

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.white
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // retrieve the ship node
```

//        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!
        let ship = scene.rootNode

While the z value for the cameraNode position is 100 or less, I can see the 3d model. But if I increase the value, then the model is no longer visible. Even at 100, parts of the model are not visible.

Is this a problem with lighting or rendering distance ? I would like to move the camera far away so that I can see the whole model on screen. Right now I can only see a part of it.  What do I need to change so I can see the whole model clearly like this:

[image]

EDIT: I am using Swift 5

Answer (score 2):

I do not use swift, but engine Cameras usually work with a `frustum`, which is a special type of collider, almost like a cone away from the camera, that decides what should be drawn and what shouldn't.

Your camera appears to be `culling` (deciding not to draw) things that are far away from it, which suggests to me that the `frustum` is too short.

The camera uses 2 `planes` to decide what the nearest object and furthest object to be drawn is.

These are called `clipping planes`, and it appears to me that your `far clipping plane` (or something similarly named), is too close to the camera.

**Tl;Dr**

Your far clipping plane is likely set too close to the camera, try and find a setting where you can change the far clipping plane of the camera to be further away.

Comment: Note that if you're trying to render objects a long way from the camera, and not close-by, then you should move *both* the near and far planes further out. If you move just the far plane, the available depth buffer precision gets stretched thin trying to cover the whole span from near to far — and most of that precision is clustered close to the near side, so you get terrible precision far out. By keeping the planes closer together, you get better depth precision in between them.

Comment: Is this specific to swift, or most/all frustum depth buffer implementations?

Comment: This is the case with all implementations. Reversing the depth buffer (so near = 1 and far = 0) helps spread the precision more evenly to avoid excessive clustering near the camera (though *some* clustering there is good since that's what's biggest on screen), but you still have only a finite number of distinct bit patterns to divide over the whole distance between near & far. The further apart those planes are, the wider each bit pattern "bucket" has to be to fill the gap, meaning more similar depths get crunched to the same number. The most common symptoms are z-fighting or shadow acne.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea camera frustums had this kind of limitation. What number of slices are there for the buffer?

Comment: That will depend on the data format of your depth buffer. Everything in your computer has this limitation. If you store something in a finite number of bits, then there's only a finite number of distinct values you can store (even if that finite number is still very very large)

Comment: Is there any way to find out how many slices there are for Unreal's or Unity's depth buffers?

Comment: As I said previously: [it depends on your depth buffer format](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture-depth.html). Comments are not for extended discussion. If you have a question about depth buffer precision after doing your research on the matter, please post a new Question.